# How can I use Core Animation within my UIView subclass drawRect function?

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, subclass

I'm starting on a project which contains the use of core animation. For the past time I've been using the UIView animation for the animation in my apps. Now I want to take my animations to a higher level by using core animation.

I'v checked out a [lesson](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243028) of [Brad Larsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) about Core Animation that explains the concept of the use of animations very well. However a decent implementation of using these animations within my (UIView subclass) own implementation is quite unclear.

At the moment I managed to create a thumbnail view of images within a scrollview. This is done by creating views within a `for-loop` and subclass these UIViews. But how should I be able to implement a animation on these views within my `drawRect` function in the UIView subclass with Core Animation. I was thinking on doing a transform with a curve to it.

My code for `drawRect` so far for drawing a white rectangle with an arc-shadow and an image on top:

```
//Draw function for displaying the seperate views/thumbnails
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect ShadowRect = CGRectMake(15,15, 130,90);
    CGRect ImageRect = CGRectMake(20,20, 120,80);

    //save context and add the arc calculation and apply it on the shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGMutablePathRef arcPath = createArcPathFromBottomOfRect(ShadowRect, 5.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, arcPath);
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0.0, 5.0), 3.0);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    //now we draw a white rectangle within the same frame as the shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGColorRef whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, whiteColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, ShadowRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [self.img drawInRect:ImageRect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CFRelease(arcPath);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you don't. You can however animate paths, shadows, and many other things in Core Animation but nothing inside drawRect.

Comment: So I'm only able to animate my views or the layers of the views (which is being shown in within Brad Larsson class)? thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't animate inside drawRect with Core Animation. You can only animate your view and layers.

However, looking at your code you should be able to do this using only Core Animation. I'm assuming that createArcPathFromBottomOfRect() creates a rounded rectangle for you with corner radius 5? If that is so, then this is very easy. If not then you may have to use a CAShapeLayer to do your more advanced path.

*If you haven't imported QuartzCore.framework into your project you will need to do that.*

### If all you are doing is creating a rounded rectangle of an image with a shadow.

Just set your image inside a `UIImageView` then set the cornerRadius property of the image views layer.

```
myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

Now, for the shadow you configure the shadow properties of the image views later.

```
myImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myImageView.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0, 5.0);
myImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
myImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
// Setting a shadow path will improve performance
myImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myImageView.bounds 
                                                          cornerRadius:myImageView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```

### If `createArcPathFromBottomOfRect()` is more complex than a rounded rectangle.

You will have to create a `CAShapeLayer` to represent your path. Luckilly it takes the CGPathRef that you are creating.

```
CAShapeLayer *myMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
myMaskLayer.path = createArcPathFromBottomOfRect(myRect, 5.0);
```

Now you can mask your image view with the path.

```
myImageView.layer.mask = myMaskLayer;
```

For the shadow you will need to create another shape layer with the same path and add the shadow to that layer (including the shadow path). Now if you add your image view above the shape layer that creates the shadow, lets call it myShadowLayer, you will have an image that is masked to some arbitrary shape with a shadow.